# Can't push a view controller again after popping it

Tags: swift, swift5, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I want to push a view controller onto the screen when a button is pressed. It works fine the first time, but when I go back and press the same button once again, it does not push the view controller again. The same problem persists when I present the view controller in fullscreen mode. But I don't face this problem when presenting the view controller in the default mode, I am able to present and dismiss the view controller as many times as I want. Someone please help me out with my problem.

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

```
import UIKit
```

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window = window
    
    return true
}
```

}

```
@objc func signUpButtonPressed() {
    
    let vc = SignUpViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
}
```

```
@objc func loginButtonPressed() {
    
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    
}

func configureNavigationBar() {
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(createButtonPressed))
    title = "Sign Up"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: Extensions.standardFont, size: 25)!]
    
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .systemBlue
    
}
```

Please ignore the scrollview in the Sign up window, it is a work in progress and does nothing at this point in time. The Login, done and create account buttons all do the same work which is to pop the signup view controller. I am able to push the signup view controller once and pop it. But if I try to press the sign up button again, the button wouldn't even respond.

Comment: No pictures of code please. Code is text. Copy and paste (and format).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you **objc func** to navigate to next view controller:

```
   @objc func signUpButtonPressedTapped() {

     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
        
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I have already used a navigation controller. My problem is that I am able to push the view controller on top of my first view controller when I first launch the app, but when I pop the view controller and push it again, it doesn't work. The button doesn't even respond when I press it the second time, I checked it using a print statement in the selector function of that button.

Comment: @SundaraAadithyan can you share some code please?

Comment: And I am not familiar with storyboard, I only do it programmatically. So if you are comfortable, please respond with a code that does not involve storyboard.

Comment: @SundaraAadithyan I told you about the storyboard because its easy to use the navigation controller there, and what I am telling you after that is not related to storyboard.

Comment: @SundaraAadithyan You have to share your code what you are doing in the button action to better understand what is wrong with your code otherwise just by saying that this thing is not working or check that thing will not work. This will be the waste of time.

Comment: @SundaraAadithyan use my code what I write above in your **objc** button functions and check if that works?

Comment: @SundaraAadithyanI tried your code and it is not working for me. You have to push the view controller as I wrote above

Comment: I have added a few pics, please take a look.

Comment: @SundaraAadithyan I had updated my answer. try it now